# How is the data access cursor performance so enhanced compared to previous versions?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, performance

The data access module was introduced with ArcGIS version 10.1.  ESRI describes the data access module as follows ([source](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000008000000)):

> The data access module, arcpy.da, is a Python module for working with
>   data. It allows control of the edit session, edit operation, improved
>   cursor support (including faster performance), functions for
>   converting tables and feature classes to and from NumPy arrays, and
>   support for versioning, replicas, domains, and subtypes workflows.

However, there is very little information regarding why cursor performance is so improved over the previous generation of cursors.

The attached figure shows the results of a benchmark test on the new `da` method UpdateCursor versus the old UpdateCursor method.  Essentially, the script performs the following workflow:

1. Create random points (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)
2. Randomly sample from a normal distribution and add value to a new
   column in the random points attribute table with a cursor
3. Run 5 iterations of each random point scenario for both the new and old UpdateCursor methods and write the mean value to lists
4. Plot the results

What is going on behind the scenes with the `da` update cursor to improve the cursor performance to the degree shown in the figure?

---

[image]

---

```
import arcpy, os, numpy, time
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

outws = r'C:\temp'
fc = os.path.join(outws, 'randomPoints.shp')

iterations = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
old = []
new = []

meanOld = []
meanNew = []

for x in iterations:
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outws, 'randomPoints', '', '', x)
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'randFloat', 'FLOAT')

    for y in range(5):

        # Old method ArcGIS 10.0 and earlier
        start = time.clock()

        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

        for row in rows:
            # generate random float from normal distribution
            s = float(numpy.random.normal(100, 10, 1))
            row.randFloat = s
            rows.updateRow(row)

        del row, rows

        end = time.clock()
        total = end - start
        old.append(total)

        del start, end, total

        # New method 10.1 and later
        start = time.clock()

        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['randFloat']) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                # generate random float from normal distribution
                s = float(numpy.random.normal(100, 10, 1))
                row[0] = s
                cursor.updateRow(row)

        end = time.clock()
        total = end - start
        new.append(total)
        del start, end, total
    meanOld.append(round(numpy.mean(old),4))
    meanNew.append(round(numpy.mean(new),4))

#######################
# plot the results

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(iterations, meanNew, label = 'New (da)')
plt.plot(iterations, meanOld, label = 'Old')
plt.title('arcpy.da.UpdateCursor -vs- arcpy.UpdateCursor')
plt.xlabel('Random Points')
plt.ylabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.legend(loc = 2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the developers of `arcpy.da` here. We got the performance where it is because *performance was our primary concern*: the main gripe with the old cursors were that they were slow, not that they lacked any particular functionality. The code uses the same underlying ArcObjects available in ArcGIS since 8.x (the CPython implementation of the search cursor, for example, looks a lot like [code samples like this in its implementation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002r6000000.htm) except, you know, in C++ instead of C#).

The main two things we did to get the speedup are thus:

1. **Eliminate layers of abstraction:** the initial implementation of the Python cursor was based on the old [Dispatch/COM based GPDispatch object](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_the_geoprocessor_object), which enabled one to use *the same API in any language that could consume [COM Dispatch objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx)*. This means that you had an API that was not particularly well-optimized for any single environment, but it also meant that there were a *lot* of layers of abstraction for the COM objects to advertise and resolve methods at runtime, for example. If you remember before ArcGIS 9.3, it was possible to write geoprocessing scripts using that same clunky interface many languages, even Perl and [Ruby](http://www.geooutlook.com/code/ruby/gp_example_rb.html). The extra paperwork an object needs to do to handle the `IDispatch` stuff adds a lot of complexity and slowdown to function calls.
2. **Make a tightly integrated, Python specific C++ library using Pythonic idioms and data structures:** the idea of [a `Row` object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000nv000000) and the really strange `while cursor.Next():` dance were just plain inefficient in Python. Fetching an item from a list is a very fast operation, and simplifies down to just a couple of CPython function calls (basically a `__getitem__` call, heavily optimized on lists). Doing `row.getValue("column")` by comparison is more heavyweight: it does a `__getattr__` to fetch the method (on which it needs to create a new bound method object), then call that method with the given arguments (`__call__`). Each part of the `arcpy.da` implementation is [*very* closely integrated with the CPython API](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/index.html) with a lot of hand-tuned C++ to make it fast, using native Python data structures (and numpy integration, too, for even more speed and memory efficiency).

You'll also notice that in nearly any benchmark ([see these slides for example](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/extend_python.pdf)), arcobjects in .Net and C++ are still over twice as fast as `arcpy.da` in most tasks. Python code using `arcpy.da` is faster, but still not faster than a compiled, lower-level language.

**TL;DR**: `da` is faster because `da` is implemented in straight-up, unadulterated Arcobjects/C++/CPython which was specifically designed to result in fast Python code.

Answer (score 4):

Performance related

- Cursor only iterates through set list of fields by default (not the entire database)

Other not directly related to performance, but nice enhancements:

- Ability to use tokens (e.g. SHAPE@LENGTH, SHAPE@XY) for accessing feature geometry
- Ability to walk through databases (using [arcpy.da.Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) method)